# Xpath how do I grab contents of an href based on the contents of the href

Tags: xpath

How do I grab the contents of an href if it includes a specific word, example:

```
<a href="/contacts.asp" class="">click here</a>
```

How do I grab 'contacts.asp' based on that it has the word 'contact' in it?

tried variations of `//a/@href[contains(@href,'contact')]` but don't seem to be getting anywhere

Comment: try `//a[contains(@href,'contact.asp')]`

Comment: Yes, but i don't know the html code will contain that '.asp', I am looking for any URLS with the word 'contact' in them.

Comment: then `//a[contains(@href,'contact')]` it will select all links contains contact link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> tried variations of `//a/@href[contains(@href,'contact')]` but don't seem to be getting anywhere

You are nearly there.

In the `contains` test, you are already in the context of the `href` attribute, so your test should be against `.` rather than the `@href` your xpath has, which is attempting to look for a `href` attribute *under* the `href` attribute. This of course won't work.

Try

```
//a/@href[contains(.,'contact')]
```

This says "find all `href` attributes on `a` elements, such that the `href` attribute value *itself* contains `contact`".

Note that this returns the `href` attribute; the library you're usnig will then have a way to pick out the value.

Comment: This is quite the same as I posted 2 hours earlier... Using your solution would come back one level to low to pick the elements content... You know this flaw, as you state this yourself in the "Note"... My solution remains on the level of  `a`, which should be better to continue... Could you please explain, why you suggested this approach?

Comment: I don't think this is the same. You return the value of the `a`, whereas I return the `href`, which is, per the question - "**How do I grab the contents of an href**" - what is being sought.

Comment: Well, maybe... It's on the OP to clearify... If I would read this question together with the existing answer I would - maybe - add a comment that you can add `/@href` to the XPath to read the value directly. But I would not add a new - in my eyes - almost identical answer. However... Happy coding!

Comment: @AakashM - your solution works perfectly, thanks. Quick question though..how do I limit the returned URL to only 1 instance? Example: //a/@href[contains(.,'contact')] returns /contact
/contact - how do I just grab one of these?

Comment: @RichStevens please could you edit that into your question so the formatting is nice, not sure what you're saying right now.

Comment: I don't know how to, I find this front end editor very unintuitive. Can't go into edit last comment either. Can't even put a line break in this thing.

Comment: @RichStevens [use this link to edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33407710/edit)

Answer (score 0):

In your Path you are **below** @href, so your contains won't work.

Try it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="//a[contains(@href,'contact')]"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Ah ok, this is a simple xapth parser I am using too, I cannot input code like that above. Only queries such as //h2, etc. Ok, I need a coder, thanks.

Comment: @RichStevens, Just try it with the one line in question: `<xsl:value-of select="//a[contains(@href,'contact')]"/>` or the XPath only: `//a[contains(@href,'contact')]`

Comment: @RichStevens, there are several online tools available to check XSLT conversions. I used this, but there are many more: http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation/#.VjHnKhwveUk You just paste the XML in one window and the XSLT in the other. The result is shown after a click on "transform"